# after inserting a script in the head tags, my menu and slide-show dies

Tags: joomla

I've recently started using joomla template SJ_News_25. I have a 'store locator' on my site which requires me to insert a script inside the  tags. when I do, it tends to kill my drop down menu.

I have noticed some code before my head tag that seems to be missing a '>' (I think). Would this be the problem? The code before the  tag is;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" <?php echo ($ytrtl == 'rtl')?'dir="rtl"':''; ?> lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>">
```

any help would be great

Comment: Run your webpage through an HTML validator and see what it says: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I did that, but couldn't make too much sense of it (i'm new to this Joomla/Web thing). The site is www.kendatires.com.au. I'm not sure if the lack of '>' above the head tag is the issue. My problem started when I included a 'store locator' which required me to insert a script inside the HEAD tags. if I include this code, it kills my menu and slide-show. I have now removed it and my menu is back working, but the slideshow has died

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a Javascript error. Those usually show in the console of the browsers developer tools / Firebug.

Looking at your page now it shows an error "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'ready'" for this Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'
    $('#null').prettyPhoto();
});
```

The problem here is that you use `$` to call jQuery, but you have jQuery loaded in noconflict mode. This means it should be `jQuery(document).ready(....)` instead.
This is the reason why the slideshow died. As for the store locator script, it may be a similar issue, but it's hard to say without seeing the actual code.
I'd first solve the issue with the slideshow and then try again to add the other script.

Comment: thanks for your help. Slideshow and menu are now working fine. I've narrowed it down to the following code. I need to enter this in between the HEAD tags, but when I do, it kills the menu and slideshow again. 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.blipstar.com/blipstarplus/prettyPhoto/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://www.blipstar.com/blipstarplus/prettyPhoto/css/prettyPhoto.css' type='text/css' media='screen'/>

Comment: I'd say the problem is when you are loading another version of jQuery. You already have jQuery (v 1.5.1) loaded for your slideshow (probably).
Now you try to load yet another jQuery version (v 1.6.4).
To add to this, you need to load jQuery with no-conflict mode enabled, which you do for your first call, but not for the second. Now it conflicts with Mootools from Joomla and maybe with the first jQuery :-)
Try to load only one and this one with no-conflict mode and see how that goes.